# How to do corpus pre-processing, lemmatization, and vectorization in SPACY NLP?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nlp

I am trying to do Tokenization, Lemmatization, and Vectorization on the folder (with .txt files) on Jupyter Notebook (Python 3) using spaCy.

Below are the codes I had tried to write, but I probably made a mistake. I want the entire folder to be Tokenized, Lemmatized, and Vectorized (not any particular .txt file but the whole bulk of it combined).

```
#tokenization
    for token in file_list:
        print(token.text, '\t', token.pos_, '\t', token.lemma, '\t', token.lemma_)

#lemmatisation 
    def show_lemmas(file_list):
        for token in text:
            print(f'{token.text:{12}} {token.pos_:{6}} {token.lemma:<{22}} {token.lemma_}') 
            show_lemmas(file_list)  

#Vectorization (Using TF-IDF to create a vectorized document term matrix)
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95,min_df=2, stop_words='english')
    dtm =tfidf.fit_transform(file_list)
    dtm
```

I expect the lines of code to be able to perform text-vectorization, lemmatization, and corpus pre-processing on the folder (with numerous .txt files). Could you please help me write the codes required to achieve that?
Also, let me know if I should be doing something more (other than Vec, Tok, and Lemm) before jumping into cluster analysis?

Comment: I suggest to split your questions i.e. not to mix more things together and be more specific. In your case I would start with searching an answer for question how to glue all the text from various text files together --> e.g how to create a list of strings from more files etc.